# Looking for a macro to expand a variable to the name + value

Tags: rpm, rpm-spec

I'll use an example to show what I mean, since it's hard to explain.

I have a `spec` file that is used for native and cross-compiling. I have many variables being passed to `rpmbuild` using the `--define` option. I'd like a macro that would be the equivalent of this:

`%{?myvar:myvar=%{myvar}}`

So, *iff* `myvar` exists, I want it to expand to `myvar=%{myvar}` which then would be `myvar=myval`.

I tried playing with `%{expand:}` a little ([src](http://www.rpm.org/wiki/PackagerDocs/Macros)), but ran into trouble when I had more than one parameter. Since it seems a macro's parameters go to EOL, and I need them all on one line in the final output, that also becomes a requirement.

I don't know `lua`, which might help to iterate over the various parameters, e.g.:

`%expvar myvar1 myvar2 myvar3` => `myvar1=myval1 myvar2=myval2 myvar3=myval3`

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand that bit about `EOL` but this works using lua.

```
%expvar() %{lua: \
    for i = 1, rpm.expand("%#") do \
        local var = rpm.expand([[%]]..i) \
        local evar = rpm.expand([[%]]..var) \
        if [[%]]..var ~= evar then \
            print(var.."="..evar.." ") \
        end \
    end \
}
```

Use is:

```
rpm -E 'blah %{expvar __cp __rm}foo'
```

Actually, given my updated understanding of what you want I think this is a better answer (though this only operates on one macro at a time):

```
%expvar() %{expand:%%{?%1:%1=%%{%1}}}
```

Use is:

```
rpm -E 'foo %{expvar __cp} %{expvar xx} %{expvar __rm} blah'
```

In theory I think it should be possible to write that as a recursive macro so it can handle multiple arguments but I've never actually been able to make that sort of thing work.

Comment: The EOL was that there's no way to *end* the parameters to a macro (that I know of) except end-of-line. So you can do:
`./configure %expvar(myvar1 myvar2 myvar3) SOMETHING=SomethingElse`

Comment: Ah, you need the `%{macro}` format for that. Example usage added and code updated for spaces and not newlines. I only tested this with `rpm -E` so it might not work exactly in an rpm but I believe it should (or at least be very close).

Comment: It does mostly what I needed. However, it seems to run always, not only if the variable already exists which is what I really needed it for, e.g.
`$ rpm -E 'blah %{expvar __cp xx}foo'
blah __cp=/usr/bin/cp xx=%xx foo
(expected)
blah __cp=/usr/bin/cp foo
` Ugh... the formatting failed here...

Comment: Ah, I missed that in the post. I can fix that but doesn't your example snippet do what you want then? `rpm -E 'foo%{?__cp:__cp=%{__cp}}%{?__xx:__xx=%{__xx}}bar'` -> `foo_cp=/bin/cpbar`?

Comment: Your second example is what I had before on my own, but didn't use the brace-enclosed syntax properly. The first one worked this morning, but somehow made the rest of the spec file invalid (it wasn't expanding {{_prefix}} any longer!?). Thanks!